# Connection between Excel and Access db 2007 version using C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Currently I'm trying to create a table in Access DB in C#, but it can't be defined in this format.

```
        if (schemaTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                con1.Open();

                sql = "CREATE TABLE newTables (";
                sql += "Idx  nvarchar(100), name nvarchar(100));";

            }
         }
```

But it is allowed to execute with following format.

```
        if (schemaTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                con1.Open();

                sql = "CREATE TABLE newTables (";
                sql += "Idx  nvarchar(100), 'name' nvarchar(100));";
             }
         }
```

And a table name is of course posted to " Idx, 'name'".

I wonder why it can't be executed this program with first format to  set the table names to " Idx, name".

Comment: [Name is a reserved word in at least some versions of Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Oh now i can create a table. Thank you for answering my question

Comment: Use table_name or similar things instead of just quoting a reserved word